Mark_text Altair doesn't working with multiple data at same month
I'm writing a code in python with altair and streamlit.
I wrote all the code and have almost everything working, but im having a issue with multiple data sum() mark_text on same month.
Example:
DT Digitacao;Descr Prod;Totais;
01/01/2024;SOLUPAN;2352
02/01/2024;SOLUPAN;2352
03/01/2024;SOLUPAN;1176
03/01/2024;SOLUPAN;588
04/01/2024;SOLUPAN;1176



import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd 
import locale
import altair as alt

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'pt_BR.UTF-8')

st.set_page_config(
    layout="wide",
    page_title="SD1 Lavadores"
)

df = pd.read_csv("consultas/scczxck0.csv", encoding='latin-1', sep=';')

#Altera o campo para data
df['DT Digitacao'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DT Digitacao'])
df['Ano'] = df['DT Digitacao'].dt.year
df['Mes'] = df['DT Digitacao'].dt.month

#Conta quantas vezes 'Descr Prod' aparece no csv
produtos = df['Descr Prod'].unique()

#Cria a selectbox de acordo com os nomes existentes
produto = st.selectbox('Nome Produto', produtos)
df_filtered = df[df['Descr Prod'] == produto]

# Calcula o custo de cada mês
total_custo = df_filtered.groupby(['Ano', 'Mes'])['Totais'].sum().reset_index(name='ValorTotal')
total_custo_2023 = total_custo[total_custo['Ano'] == 2023]

# Filtra os dados apenas para o ano de 2023
df_filtered_2023 = df_filtered[df_filtered['Ano'] == 2023]

# Gráfico de barras custo mensal 2023
grafico_custo_2023 = alt.Chart(df_filtered_2023).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('Mes:N', axis=alt.Axis(title='Mês'.upper())),
    y=alt.Y('Totais:Q', axis=alt.Axis(title='Custo Total por Mês'.upper()), scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0, 30000])),
            ).interactive()

# Adiciona rótulos de dados com o custo total de cada mês 2023
custo_2023 = alt.Chart(total_custo_2023).mark_text(
    align='center',
    baseline='middle',
    dx=0,
    dy=-7,  # Ajuste para posicionar o texto acima das barras
    fontSize=14  # Define o tamanho da fonte do rótulo
).encode(
    x=alt.X('Mes:N', axis=alt.Axis(title='Mês'.upper())),
    y=alt.Y('ValorTotal:Q'),
    text=alt.Text('ValorTotal:Q', format='$,.2f')  # Formata o texto para exibir moeda
)

grafico_final_custo2023 = (grafico_custo_2023 + custo_2023).properties(width=600, height=400)

# Coluna 1
col1, col2 = st.columns(2)

with col1:
    st.markdown("<h2 style='text-align: center; color: black;'>Custo de Compra Mensal 2023</h2>", unsafe_allow_html=True)
    col1.altair_chart(grafico_final_custo2023, use_container_width=True)


I have tha same product, but 2 buys at March, and this is what i got:
RIGHT
It shows the correct sum, but at March or everyone that have multiple buys in the same month, it shows the correct values separated if i put my mouse on it, but doesn't show the mark_text with the sum().
Tried other methods of writing, but can't fix it, and always with the same problem.

I can't reproduce the example chart with the data you posted, but I think you might just need to add 'sum()' on you y-axis encodings to make sure they are summed up instead of two separate stacked bars. For details, see https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/encodings/index.html#encoding-shorthands

It wasn't 'sum()' on y-axis, i decided to go to my read.csv and found that float values was write with ',' instead of '.'. Changed it and it works.
Thanks for replying!
